# Which image class should I use from .net to make a library more generic as possible?

Tags: c#, dll, .net-4.0

I'm building a library that I would like to make it as generic as possible. Specifically, I would like that it will work both on Winform and WPF (ok WPF is more important by the way).

This image class must support 4 byte colors (ARGB) because I must convert it in QVGA format (is used by Lg screen of my G19 keyboard). if it supports qvga format, this is always better.

If it doesn't support QVGA natively, it must support "fast" operations to copy it (byte per byte) to an array of 320x240x4 where obviusly I'll reorganize bytes in correct order.

So the only image class I've used so far from C# is Bitmap, and it worked so far. However I don't think that class is used in WPF.

What should I use to support, if not both WPF and winforms, at least WPF (I think it's more important).

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Bitmap` and `Image` classes are supported and used in WPF. Don't hesitate to use them and base your class library on them. If you want to have a generic image manipulation library that would work in WPF, WinForms, ASP.NET, Silverlight, Console applications, that's exactly the kind of classes that you need.